# Any alternatives to socat and netcat for port forwarding?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, iptables, netcat, socat

I need to forward an exposed port of a Docker container to a remote port of a remote server. There are two approaches. One is with IP tables, but this wouldn't work for me since I'm not able to give NET_ADMIN access to my containers, which will be running on a cloud provider's Kubernete hosting platform.
The second approach would be to utilize SOCAT, but that has it's own problems since it forks a process for each connection, reaching the maximum allowed open files in no time since I have thousands of concurrent connections.

Are there any alternatives, which can forward a port like iptables does, but without NET_ADMIN requirements, and without needing to create a process for each connection?

Comment: You probably mean it reaches the maximum allowed processes? When you are dealing with UDP you might try to use total timeout in Socat.
Exhausting the maximum number of open files will happen with any user space solution that does not fork.

Answer (score 2):

**Check below options :**

1)If you want to connect to a port on a specific IP address without the use of netcat.

Try this `telnet host.example.com port` (e. g. `telnet www.example.com 80`).

Another possibility is `/dev/tcp:`

`$ echo "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" >/dev/tcp/[www.example.com/80][1]`.

2)There's a tiny, light resources program called `redir` which is pretty configurable.

`apt-get install redir` to install on Debian-based distributions.

`redir :SRC :DEST` will run in the background as a daemon.

3)`Rinetd`, It's a daemon that redirects TCP connections. Have a look at the man page to see if it suits your needs: https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/rinetd/rinetd.8.en.html

4)`portfwd`, (TCP and UDP forwarding) https://[portfwd.sourceforge.net](https://portfwd.sourceforge.net/)/, (it latest release is 2007, and it works on 2.6 kernel).